# Why do I get [object Object] in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here's my simple function to hide an input value on click and show it again on blur:

```
// show input value then hide on click
$('.showHide').click(function() {
    var originalValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("value", '');
});
$('.showHide').blur(function(originalValue) {
    $(this).attr("value", originalValue);
});
```

But showing the original value again isn't working, instead I get this: `[object Object]` on blur, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a scope issue

```
// show input value then hide on click
var originalValue;
$('.showHide').click(function() {
    originalValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("value", '');
});
$('.showHide').blur(function() {
    $(this).attr("value", originalValue);
});
```

should work

Answer (score 2):

When blur calls your handler function it is passing an event object, not the original value. Try storing the value like this:

```
// show input value then hide on click
$('.showHide').click(function() {
    jQuery.data($(this), 'originalValue', $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("value", '');
});
$('.showHide').blur(function() {
    $(this).attr("value", jQuery.data($(this), 'originalValue'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive without seeing your html but I think your problem may be the local declaration of originalValue in the first function and trying to use it in the second function. Try this:

```
// show input value then hide on click
var originalValue = "";
$('.showHide').click(function() {
    originalValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("value", '');
});
$('.showHide').blur(function(originalValue) {
    $(this).attr("value", originalValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `originalValue` is within the scope of the function it was declared in, and doesn't exist outside of it. You need to declare it outside of the function first.
2. The value that gets passed into an event callback is the event object. As such, in the `blur` callback function, `originalValue` is set to the event object, which is why it is non-null.

What you want is something like this:

```
var originalValue;

$('.showHide').click(function() {
    originalValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("value", '');
});
$('.showHide').blur(function() {
    $(this).attr("value", originalValue);
});
```